# Less percentage to pixels

Tags: less

I have a variable:

@index = 3;

I want to make a square:

```
width: (100% / 12) * @index;
```

but I don't what value I have to give to height:

```
height: (100% / 12) * @index;
```

It is not ok.

Is there a way to make the width same as height without using js or viewport-relative lengths vw, vh, vm or height: 0px and padding bottom: some px.

I want to know if there is a less option.

Thank you

Comment: Less can do only what CSS can. So no, there's no solution beside common CSS tricks (in particular that `width: 50%; padding-bottom: 50%;` you mentioned).

Comment: Thank you ... I used jQuery